# Error while uploading Template assembly with TcmUploadAssembly.exe to 2013 SP1

Tags: templating

I am trying to upload a new Template assembly to SDL Tridion 2013 SP1, using tcmUploadAssembly.exe. It fails with error:

> "Error: Could not load type
>   'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute'from assembly
>   'mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'."

The Target Framework used for the Template assembly is 4.5.
The upload command:

```
TcmUploadAssembly.exe upload.conf  ..\Some.Templates\bin\Debug\Some.Templates.dll /folder:tcm:1-10-2
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using `Framework 2.0 (mscorlib.dll)`. `TargetFrameworkAttribute` is available only from `Framework 4.0 (mscorlib.dll)`.

Comment: My templates project is 4.5 based. So what is causing this use of 2.0? Any hints where I might look?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that this issue was caused because of an upload to the wrong CMS. We are dealing with multiple versions: 2009 to 2013 SP1. It seems that an assembly that was meant to be uploaded to 2013SP1, was in fact being uploaded to 2009. Hence the confusion with the different versions of the Target Framework.

Comment: Having the right CMS can actually be *harder* than having the right publication (where you can check visually). Thanks for following up.